# Window Server 2012 & SQL Server 2012 within single VM on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

According to [this link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/) we can not use on premise licence for Window server but we can use for SQL server. Now my requirement as per below,

I would like to spin up Window server 2012 on medium instance and within the same server i would like to install SQL server (with on premise sql server licence), Is it possible?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arun Rana,

That should be possible and AFAIK there isn't any restriction for SQL Server licence to be used in Azure, however take a look at [License Mobility through Software Assurance on Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/license-mobility/).

If your licence is from MSDN, then it now [absolutely legal](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/06/03/windows-azure-announcing-major-improvements-for-dev-test-in-the-cloud.aspx) use it on Azure.

If you are unsure about the licence problem and other litigation, you may spin up a VM with SQL Server 2012 pre-installed and this will solve your licence trouble (but right now only available with the combo of SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2).

**PS / Personal Experience** : SQL Server + some server component isn't performing well for a Medium instance. Either split the server roles or consider choosing a bigger instance size like **xLarge or A6**.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any price difference according to image we are going to select (in case of SQL Server 2012 on window server 2012)?  and if i am select only window server than i need to install sql server manually and need to follow the steps of licence mobility,right?

Comment: Yes there will be a pricing impact. SQL Server on Windows Server VM cost slightly more as it includes the **licencing cost**. Check out the azure [pricing page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines) for mode info. The base Windows Server (Medium) costs $0.18 / hour and SQL Server (Medium) cost **$0.225/hour** for **Web**, **$0.73/hour** for **Standard**, **$2.28/hour** for **Enterprise**